# CTFontManagerRegister... for a 3rd-party app

Tags: macos, cocoa, fonts, core-text

This is a bit basic but I have been struggling finding good documentation around NSFontManager and CTFontManager to achieve this. So here's the scenario:

1. Keynote (or any other existent app from a different developer) opens a file which uses a font that's not activated.
2. My app has the font and I use CTFontManagerRegisterFontURLs or one of the similar methods to get it activated.
3. Keynote gets a notification that the font is now available.

I would imagine there's a NSFontManager notification for missing fonts, but haven't found anything. The notifications seem to be within the sandbox of my own app. Does anyone here have an idea where I can find anything that does this (or *almost* does this)?

Thank you so much.